# Limit text-blocks from stringbuilder append to the fixed container height

Tags: c#, asp.net, json.net, stringbuilder

In my client company website homepage I am showing the company's Facebook timeline updates in a fixed size container with no scrollbar (CSS `overflow-y: hidden`).
The client company wanted to show the FB updates filling the container.
Even though visually hiding the messages beyond the container height, sometimes part of the hidden text / image shown which I would like to avoid. See the picture below.

Example screenshots (jpg):

[image]

[image]

As per the above pictures  I would like to totally remove every thing from partly shown (highlighted) to all hidden text blocks written by `StringBuilder`. But I cannot show fixed 5 text-blocks because each message can have images or longer text content. Visually fit the content to the container height.

How I fetch the data and filter:
I am getting the Facebook JSON (`http://graph.facebook.com/USERID/feed?&limit=20`) and de-serializing with JSON.net library. After filtering the invalid messages by some conditions I am showing the valid ones. Still there are too many messages.

As in the above url, through limit query string I can limit the messages that can fit to the height of the container. But because of "invalid message" filters there is a possibility of very less or no message shown.

Please help me to limit the stringbuilder to dynamically write the text blocks within the container height. no hidden DOM elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently I found a client side solution.

Through jquery I am hiding the unneeded blocks beyond the fixed conatainer height. The below code will make sure that the overflow content blocks will not be shown at all.

```
$('#fbtl').children(".fbpost").each(function () {
 if (($(this).position().top + $(this).height() + parseInt($(this).css('padding-bottom'), 10) - 93) > $('#fbtl').height()) {
 $(this).hide();
});
```

Cheers,

Shanthosh Krishnakumar